# Inserting a side col inside the content when going mobile (bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout like so in md/lg (pardon the horrible pain):

[image]

In sm/xs my designer wants it to become:

[image]

My current markup is:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        content1
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        content2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      side col<br />
      side col<br />
      side col<br />
      side col<br />
      side col<br />
      side col<br />
      side col<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously with this the side col gets below the contents, not between.

I've tried a lot of things, I don't think it's doable in pure CSS/HTML, unless I use a duplicate column that's visible-xs only and make the other one hidden-xs...

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there can be `col-xs-60 col-md-50` in `twitter-bootstrap`. It can be only upto `12`

Comment: We're using a custom version of bootstrap (made with (http://bootstrapk.com/customize) with 60 col. Not my choice. Imagine 60 as 12 and 50 as 10.

Comment: If you can post an images/mockups of what you're trying to acheive between viewport change it would make this simpler to understand.

Comment: I edited my question with two not-so-awesome paint drawings and I changed my markup to match the standard 12 col system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, just add class `pull-right` and re-order your col like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10" style="background:red">
        content1
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 pull-right" style="background:gray">
      side col<br />
      side col<br />
      side col<br />
      side col<br />
      side col<br />
      side col<br />
      side col<br />
    </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10" style="background:green">
        content2
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a33duo7a/1/) (resize the width and you can see the cols change)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.


For the 12 col parts, we are using a customized version of bootstrap with 60 cols, sadly. I forgot to change the cols to ask my question.


In your example the two contents are side by side, i need them one below the other.

Comment: @Growiel ok, sorry for misunderstand, see my edit and let me know if it like you want